# Minimum Absolute Difference

Tags: optimization, absolute-value, median

Given 'n' numbers, how do we choose 'k' (k<=n) numbers such that the sum of the absolute difference between each element in 'n' and the closest element in 'k' is the minimum. Each of these 'n' numbers are between 1 and 1000.

For k=1, this is the median of the 'n' numbers and for k=n, this is the 'n' numbers itself. But what if 'k' is something else? How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Your problem is essentially [$k$-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) in one dimension, so you might find it interesting to research about $k$-means clustering or things like "$k$-means clustering in one dimension".

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth: more precisely, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids.

Comment: But is it possible to obtain an optimal solution for this? Isn't k-means and k-medains approximation algorithms?

Comment: @ShyamnathPrem: k-means and k-medioids are not algorithms, they are mathematical definitions. Your question *is* about the k-medioids. Unfortunately, there are no fast exact algorithms.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth: [Ckmeans.1d.dp: Optimal $k$-means Clustering in One Dimension by Dynamic Programming](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Wang+Song.pdf)